# always get Crashlytics is modified when doing git status, objective c, git

Tags: iphone, objective-c, git

I am using Crashlytics framework for crash reporting. After running the project from xcode and   doing `git status`, I always get the message like below

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Crashlytics.framework/Versions/A/Crashlytics
    modified:   Crashlytics.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Info.plist
    modified:   Crashlytics.framework/run
```

Please advice me on how to get rid of these modified files from Crashlytics

---

@Abizem : what I did for .gitignore is following

```
.DS_Store
#backups
*.swp
*~.nib
*~.xib
*~

*.zip
*.gz

build
*.[oa]
DerivedData
VERSION-FILE
Crashlytics.framework/
#XCode
*.pbxuser
*.mode1
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.perspective
*.perspectivev3
project.xcworkspace/
xcuserdata/
```

but it still does not work.

Answer (score 7):

You have two choices:

1. Check the changes into your project, which will stop the cause of the error.
2. Add the Crashlytics.framework to your .gitignore file which will ignore any changes to the file.

Comment: I have Crashlytics.framework and Crashlytics.framework/ in my .gitignore file (and you'll notice OP has the latter as well) and I'm still getting these files showing up as modified in my git status all the time. Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: To previous commenter: You added Crashlytics.framework to .gitnore, but only after it was already committed. Now you need to delete it and commit the changes, and the ignore will work.

Comment: Which one of these choices is recommended?

Answer (score 3):

The Crashlytics Mac app used to automatically update instances of its frameworks in your projects, which caused the original confusion. With the newer Fabric app, updates are controlled manually so you shouldn’t see unexpected changes in your working copy.

If you want to be able to able to return to the exact state of your application source at any time, you should add the framework files to your version control system and update them every time the framework updates.

Alternatively, ignore changes to the framework if you want to avoid adding possibly large files to your version control system or save yourself the time it takes to commit the changes — at the expense of having a complete source history. Disk space and network speeds are going up, while discarded history is lost forever. To read more, see the answers to [*Binaries in source control* on Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110518/binaries-in-source-control).

A third option that has some of the advantages of each choice is to use a separate repository for tracking changes to the Crashlytics/Fabric frameworks and add it as a submodule of your main repository. For example, see [*CrashlyticsFramework* by Bogdan Poplauschi](https://github.com/bpoplauschi/CrashlyticsFramework).

Comment: Mike from the Crashlytics and Fabric teams here. With the Fabric app, you can completely control when the framework updates happen. Just use the Kit Selector in the top-right corner to decide when to update.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This is a great improvement. I've updated my answer.